# Magick++ Memory leak in compositing algorithm

Tags: c++, memory, imagemagick, magick++

I have a program which emulates Windows 10 background fade transition in Linux. Originally I was accomplishing this using a `System()` call to the ImageMagick `composite -blend` command, however in an attempt to eliminate the `System()` call, I wrote the below function to emulate the ImageMagick command:

```
                A=Image(newpic);
                B=Image(picpath+".cache/resizeOld"+to_string(S)+".jpg");

                if(i<=steps)
                {
                    stream<<std::hex<<int(i*(255/steps));
                    streambuffer=stream.str();
                    if(streambuffer.length()==1)
                    {
                        streambuffer="0"+streambuffer;
                    }
                    color=streambuffer;
                    streambuffer="";
                    stream.str("");
                }
                else
                {
                    color="FF";
                }

                maskA=Image(Geometry(bgW,bgH),Color("#"+color+color+color));
                maskB=Image(Geometry(bgW,bgH),Color("#"+invertHex(color)+invertHex(color)+invertHex(color)));

                A.composite(maskA,0,0,Magick::CopyAlphaCompositeOp);
                B.composite(maskB,0,0,Magick::CopyAlphaCompositeOp);

                compResult=A;
                compResult.composite(B,0,0,Magick::BlendCompositeOp);
                compResult.write((picpath+".cache/transition"+to_string((int)i)+".jpg").c_str());
```

This is inside a `for` loop to get all necessary transition steps.

The general purpose of the above algorithm is as follows:

1. Read in new background image
2. Read in old background image
3. Create a mask for new image
4. Create an inverted mask for old image
5. Apply respective masks to respective images as an alpha channel
6. Composite both masked images together
7. Write resulting composited image to file for later use in program

I'm not really sure what's causing the memory leak, since I am explicitly using an `=` operator for each image, which I would think would prevent a leak since so far as I can tell, nothing is getting constantly added on to.

The built-in `composite -blend` ImageMagick function doesn't change memory usage at all, so it seems like it's my algorithm somehow.

Comment: What is the structure of class Image?

Comment: @srt1104 What do you mean exactly? As I understand it, pt's an object that is defined by the Magick++ library.